# apache server-status connection/child/slot explanation

Tags: apache

In apache server-status page,referring to the "Acc" column, which is the "Number 
of accesses this connection / this child / this slot".

For example 18/256/356, I will expect that all values are equal.

I need an explanation of what is meant by child and slot connection with examples.

Answer (score 4):

From this [mailing list archive](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/339540), we can give the following definitions :

> - A **child** is a process or a thread that handles requests.
> - A **slot** is a placeholder for a child. There may or may not be a child
>     there depending on max/min spare servers.
> - A **connection** is a link between a client and a child which resides in a slot.